# Multiple Swiper Arrow Navigation Only Working on a single slider

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm working with Swiper and I have the following code setup:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>

var swiper2 = new Swiper(".swiper2", {
  effect: 'coverflow',
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 30,
    slideShadows: false,
  },
  direction: "horizontal",
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: {
   delay: 2000,
 },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true
  },
  speed: 300,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    },
    // when window width is >= 768px
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2
    },
    // when window width is >= 992px
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 3
    }
  },

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  
    scrollbar: {
    hide: true,
  },
});

var swiper3 = new Swiper(".swiper3", {
  effect: 'coverflow',
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 30,
    slideShadows: false,
  },
  direction: "horizontal",
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: {
   delay: 2000,
 },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true
  },
  speed: 300,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    },
    // when window width is >= 768px
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2
    },
    // when window width is >= 992px
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 3
    }
  },

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  
    scrollbar: {
    hide: true,
  },
});

var swiper4 = new Swiper(".swiper4", {
  effect: 'coverflow',
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 30,
    slideShadows: false,
  },
  direction: "horizontal",
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  loop: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: {
   delay: 2000,
 },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true
  },
  speed: 300,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    },
    // when window width is >= 768px
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2
    },
    // when window width is >= 992px
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 3
    }
  },

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  
    scrollbar: {
    hide: true,
  },
});
```

I've looked up various solutions online and as far as I understand, each of these sliders' arrows that move it left and right should be only impacting the slider they are tied to but all the arrows on each slider are moving all of the sliders at the same time. Anyone have an idea what's causing this? Thanks for your time!

**ADDITIONAL INFO: I am working in Webflow**

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly from the last time I was using this, you should also use unique class names for the pagination elements like
`pagination: { el: '.swiper-pagination2', },`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So when I make the pagination unique, the second and third slider arrows work, but move the first slider. I also tried to make the prev and next buttons unique, but then they disappear. Appreciate your assistance!

Comment: As an example you can see three different sliders working here:
https://codepen.io/intotheprogram/pen/BaaeyxM